# cannot use line_profiler in jupyter/python2.7.5

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, line-profiler

I'm trying to use the line magic %lprun in jupyter notebook running a python 2.7.5 kernel.

The code I'm trying to run is the following:

```
%load_ext line_profiler
distance = 20
veg_slope = 0
slope = 10
%lprun test = bal.run('forest', veg_slope, slope, distance, FFDI=100)
```

The bal.run code is a bit complicated, but executing the code with those parameters will output the following tuple:

```
(35.02405579440225, 'BAL-40')
```

However if I try to use the %lprun magic I get the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
test = bal.run(\'forest\', veg_slope, slope, distance, FFDI=100)
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Not sure what is happening there, but as a test I tried to run a simple python function like print together with the line_profiler, and that worked.

Anyone has any idea of what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same issue in Jupyter / Python 3.6 using example code from a presentation [available here.](https://github.com/s-heisler/pycon2017-optimizing-pandas)

I'm still a newbie but the traceback ends with the same syntax error:

File "", line 1
    df[\'high_rate_normalized\'] = normalize(df, df[\'high_rate\'])
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Answer (score 0):

Change to double quotes "

```
%lprun test = bal.run("forest", veg_slope, slope, distance, FFDI=100)
```

Comment: didn't work for me, had to `var = "str" `and `%lprun func(var)`